# Using mapply with '...'

Tags: r, dplyr

in R, I am trying to pass optional arguments `...` to a custom function using `mapply` without success. Here is what I am trying to do:

I have defined a function as:

```
require(dplyr) 
CustomFunc <- function(...,a,b) {
Data %>% 
         mutate (X1 = a * Column1,
                 X2 = b * Column2) %>%
         group_by(...) %>%
         summarise( GrandTotal =sum(X1/X2) )
}
```

I can use this function just fine by passing for example

```
CustomFunct(a= 4, b = 7)
```

or for example this also works:

```
CustomFunct(ColumnHeader1,ColumnHeader2,
            a= 4, b = 7)
```

the key here is to note that the first argument(s) `...` is/are optional and can be of variable length (here I am passing `ColumnHeader1` and `ColumnHeader2`)

I want however to see the results from `CustomFunct` for cartesian joins of arrays of inputs for both a and b such as:

```
a <- c(3,6,12,24)
b <- c(1,7)
```

I have created all combinations of `a` and `b` using the following:

```
inputs <- expand.grid( a = c(3,6,12,24), 
                       b = c(1,7) )
```

I can get `CustomFunct` to work using the following code

```
mapply(CustomFunct,
       a = inputs$a,
       b = inputs$b)
```

What I am looking for however is to be able to pass the optional arguments `...` to `CustomFunct`, with what in my head would look something like:

```
mapply(CustomFunct,
       ... = list(ColumnHeader1,ColumnHeader2),
       a = inputs$a,
       b = inputs$b)
```

This however doesn't work. Can someone please help me finding the right syntax?

Comment: Note that **you should not use `require`**. It silently swallows errors; use `library` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using dplyr instead:

```
inputs %>% rowwise() %>% do(CustomFunc(ColumnHeader1, a=.$a, b=.$b))
```

Comment: @great idea, works "out of the box" on my NSE function

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `... =` and the list:

```
mapply(CustomFunct,
       ColumnHeader1, ColumnHeader2,
       a = inputs$a,
       b = inputs$b)
```

However, your `CustomFunct` uses non-standard evaluation in its `...` arguments. This is fine on its own, but `mapply` performs standard evaluation of all its arguments. As a consequence, `mapply` will complain that `ColumnHeader1` doesn’t exist. To work around this, use the standard-evaluation dplyr functions (`group_by_` in this case):

```
CustomFunc <- function(..., a, b) {
    Data %>% 
        mutate(X1 = a * Column1,
               X2 = b * Column2) %>%
        group_by_(...) %>%
        summarize(GrandTotal = sum(X1 / X2))
}

mapply(CustomFunct, 'Columnheader1', 'ColumnHeader2',
       a = inputs$a, b = inputs$b)
```

If you want to continue using `CustomFunct` with non-standard evaluation, you should do what dplyr does, and provide two versions: NSE `CustomFunct`, and standard evaluation `CustomFunct_`, and then use `mapply` with the latter.

Comment: or use `do.call` if the list is passed programmatically.

Comment: Hi Konrad, using your suggestion I get the following error 'Error in mapply(decay_rate, prtf, status, inputs$lookback_periods, inputs$starting_points) : 
  object 'prtf' not found

Comment: @Olivier The error message indicates what the problem is, and it’s unrelated to the `mapply` call; rather, you haven’t defined the `prtf` object.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter in error previously ; when using your syntax, I get this error `Error in mapply(CustomFunc, ColumnHeader1, inputs$a, inputs$b) :   object 'ColimnHeader1' not found'`

Comment: @Olivier Same as before. But I see now that you’re using non-standard evaluation, which changes things. Stay tuned for an update.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Many thanks - your solution works with the example I provided. it is however coercing the output to lists within what is seemingly a matrix, so I just need to play with the output now

Comment: @Olivier Yes, `mapply`, like `sapply`, does some output coercion which is rarely what you want. I suggest using `Map` instead, or setting `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` (which is what `Map` does internally).